# Embedded controller has nil outlets

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

In the storyboard, I embedded controller B into controller A. However when I try to access the outlets in controller B **from** controller B's  viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, or viewDidAppear methods, they're nil.

Why would an embedded controller's own outlets be nil after the view has loaded?

Comment: I tried the following steps: new project with single view template, create a second view controller subclass, add a container view to my first controller, set the class of the contained controller, add a button to the contained controller and make an outlet connection, print the value of the button in `viewDidLoad` of the second controller.  Result: the connection is good.  Maybe you can compare what you're doing to a working simple case.

Comment: @PhillipMills Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Sample project here if you're willing to look:  https://github.com/AaronBratcher/Tester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building your LiveView controls in a storyboard scene that's not being used.  Move your various views and buttons into the scene that's connected to your container view by the embed segue.

Comment: hmmm you're right.  Different view, same class. Duh!  so if I want to use the same VC in different controllers, I'll need to do it programatically

Comment: When you drop a view controller into a storyboard, you're essentially creating an object.  You can create multiple ones (and load them however you like) but, being separate objects, they don't share attribute settings.

Comment: Had a blonde moment :)